# Domain specific pages in rails

Tags: url, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, dns

Is there a way to make a domain/url specific pages?

mysite.com will have a different homepage than mysite.net

Is it routing or some query inside the page?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing called domain  specific pages, They do to keep things dynamic is that, they load the page details according to the domain

Ex:

in rails you could get the ip by `request.ip`, then in the table you have the details for a given page according to the ip

simple example would be, say you have the following table

```
sites
------------------------------
| id | site_name | ip         |
------------------------------- 
| 1 | demo site | 192.168.0.1 |
-------------------------------

pages
-------------------------------------------
|id | page_name | page_content | site_id |
-------------------------------------------
| 1 | home      | some content | 1       |
-------------------------------------------
```

when you load the home page. you could get the current ip and from that you can find the site, once you have the site you can find all the pages according to that site

And to keep this dynamic pages more manageable you could make use of gems like [liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/) (http://liquidmarkup.org/)

check these screen casts we well

[dynamic layouts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/125-dynamic-layouts)

[subdomains](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains)